# How to pass array to Mailgun api via http post in Ionic 5 Application?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, ionic-framework, mailgun

I am trying to send some images URL to Mailgun API to be used my Mailgun Email Templates variables. But I am unable to figure out how to pass. I can pass single variables using v: but don't know how to pass an array. I have tried passing the javascript object to Http post method but Mailgun API gives "from parameter is missing" error.

```
using this way I am able to send data to mailgun api without any issues but don't know how to send array or json object. 

var body = 
            "from=Admin <order@xyz.com>" + 
            "&to=" + recipient + 
            "&subject=Order Placed #" + subject +
            "&template=my-template" + 
            "&v:orderID=" + subject +
            "&v:userEmail=" + JSON.parse(address).email +
            "&v:orderCharges=" + this.price * quantity +
            "&v:frameQuantity=" + quantity +
            "&v:orderShipping=" +  JSON.parse(address).addr +
            "&v:orderImage[]=" + encodeURI (message[0]) + "," + encodeURI(message[1]);

        var url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + this.mailgunUrl + "/messages";

        this.http.post(url,body, 
        {
                headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + this.mailgunApiKey, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            }).subscribe(res => {
                console.log('THIS IS EMAIL RES', res);
            })
    }
```

When I try to pass an object like this:

```
{
    "from":"order@xyz.com",
    "to": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
    "subject": "Order Placed #46",
    "template": "my-template",
    "v:orderID": 46
}
```

Mailgun API gives me error "from parameter is missing. I have trying from:order@xyz.com as well. Even tried passing json object after url to post but still same error.

I have managed to send data to mailgun api by constructing the body as shown above but now I don't know how to pass array because I don't know how many images user will select. So I want an array to be used by Handlebars.js each loop to translate variables into data.

Comment: I have followed the tutorial from this guide to integrate mailgun in ionic: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/04/send-emails-ionic-framework-app-via-mailgun-api/

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use templates for dynamic data, such as arrays, In Mailgun.

Instead you can apply a trick.

Create your template in the Mailgun & test it. When that makes ready, copy it's HTML code to a string variable in your source code & fill it with your array data.

Then send this string variable as the html attribute of Mailgun API.